# Could you help me to fix this problem: "end of line without continuation"

Tags: pine-script

There is a piece of code in Pine v3.
Line: `DivBull =`  has an error `end of line without continuation`.

I have no idea how to fix it.

```
DivergenceSource=input(close)
highHist=outHist
highHist:=outHist>0 and outHist[1]<0?outHist:outHist<0?0:outHist>highHist[1]?outHist:highHist[1]
highprice=DivergenceSource
highprice:=highHist==0?0:highHist>highHist[1]?DivergenceSource:highprice[1]
highHist_=highHist
highHist_:=highHist==0 and highHist[1]>0?highHist[1]:highHist_[1]
highprice_=highprice
highprice_:=highprice==0 and highprice[1]>0?highprice[1]:highprice_[1]
DivBull = (highHist_[1]>highHist[1] and highprice_[1]<highprice[1]) and ((highHist>0 and (highHist==highHist[1] and highHist!=highHist[2])) or (highHist==0 and outHist[1]==highHist_)
bgcolor((highHist_[1]>highHist[1] and highprice_[1]<highprice[1]) and ((highHist>0 and (highHist==highHist[1] and highHist!=highHist[2])) or (highHist==0 and outHist[1]==highHist_))?red:na,transp=50,offset=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one extra `(` in `((highHist>0 and (highHist==highHist[1] and highHist!=highHist[2]))`

Change it to:

```
DivBull = (highHist_[1]>highHist[1] and highprice_[1]<highprice[1]) and (highHist>0 and (highHist==highHist[1] and highHist!=highHist[2])) or (highHist==0 and outHist[1]==highHist_)
```